# Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment arrays

Tags: javascript

```js
class arrays_1 {
    constructor(name,age,roll,score){
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.roll = roll;
        this.score = score;
    }
}
const students = [
    new arrays_1 = ('a', 24, true, 33),
    new arrays_1 = ('b', 44, false, 123),
    new arrays_1 = ('c', 14, true, 333),
    new arrays_1 = ('d', 64, false, 63),
];

const resultArray = students.find(function(this,value,idx){
    console.log(this);
    console.log(value);
    console.log(idx);
})
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: [JS docs](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference) and [JS tutorials](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide) are both available. The logged error also tells you which line the error occurred on; from there it should be trivial to look up the corresponding documentation. What makes you think that `new arrays_1 = ('a', 24, true, 33)` is valid syntax?

Comment: Oh, my God. Oh, my God, how did I make this mistake? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`students` should be:

```
const students = [
    new arrays_1('a', 24, true, 33),
    new arrays_1('b', 44, false, 123),
    new arrays_1('c', 14, true, 333),
    new arrays_1('d', 64, false, 63),
];
```

Comment: That's what I was about to post!